# Recover Skype deleted message and deleted conversation history in Win 10

Tags: windows-10, skype, history

When referring to messages when using Skype, a deleted message means a deleted single message, in contrast to a deleted conversation which means that the user has deleted an entire conversation by right clicking the avatar on the left.

I am pretty sure that the deleted message I wish to recover is in fact recoverable as Skype keeps deleted messages on a Cloud. I discovered this when I opened the Skype app on a new device and saw that the Skype app will download the chat history slowly, **including** the deleted messages, and then proceed to remove the deleted message after one second.

The issue is then that when I try to directly export the Skype chat history from the Cloud directly, both the deleted message and conversation are gone.

Is it still possible to recover the chat history from Skype, especially an entirely deleted conversation?

---

By the way, the newest win 10 Skype (appstore version) no longer keep a "main.db" file.

Answer (score 1):

The `main.db` file stores a copy of the chat history.

1. On your PC, press Win+R to open the Run dialog box.
2. Type in `%appdata%\Skype` and press enter.
3. Open the folder named after your Skype Name.
4. Find the main.db file in the folder.

Use the application [SkypeLogView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/skype_log_view.html) to read the main.db file.

Comment: I tried this but I don't think this includes the deleted chats?

Answer (score 0):

If you had enabled Previous Versions feature in Windows, before losing the Skype chats, then you can go to
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Skype\ and right click your user name > Properties > Previous Versions tab and click the Old folder and Restore.